# How can I flip this photo?

Tags: html, css

I've just created a simple page with some text and a picture, but I can't figure it out how I can make the image flip.

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

    @keyframes flip {
        0% {
            transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            transform: rotate3d(360deg, 360deg, 360deg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not how CSS `@keyframes` work.  Refer to MDN for info on how `animation` and `keyframes` in CSS work together.

Comment: You've got syntax issues etc, might refer to an already working example of which there's loads [available on the internet](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_box.asp) to reference.

Comment: @Derp Please explain (in your question) which example on the internet you tried and how it didn't work. Did you get error messages?

Comment: Have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation which will help you sort out your syntax errors, then if still stuck put your code so far as a runnable snippet into your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. To make sure you don’t have syntax errors put your code through a validator and use your browsers dev tools inspect facility to pin down exactly what CSS is and isn’t being applied.

Answer (score 1):

As Deepak Kamat mentioned, you can find reference on how to use it searching on google, such as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) example, which shows how animation and keyframs work together in css.

```css
    img {
      animation: flip 3s infinite;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    @keyframes flip{
      0%   {transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0);}
      20%  {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);}
      40%  {transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,360deg);}
      60%  {transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,180deg);}
      80%  {transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);}
      100% {transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,360deg);}
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/800px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" alt="Google Logo Image">
```